# how to dynamically add rows and columns in table layout panel

Tags: c#, database

I am working on windows application in C#.I have created one windows form,in that I have added one table panel control.In database I am having one table which is having 4 columns like book name,book image,book category and book sub category.Now I am having 10 records in a table.

I want to show all those data in table panel.I have tried following code.But I am not getting proper output.I have to add one picture box control and three label control i.e I have to create 4 columns ,so Column 1 will have picture box and other three columns have one label in each.The code I try gives me the output,but it is not proper.It shows picture box image in all 4 columns,then labels.

But I want to show the output like,each column should contain unique data.

Code:

```
public void DynamicGenerateTable(int columnCount, int rowCount)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        //Clear out the existing row and column styles
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();

        //Assign table no of rows and column
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = columnCount;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = rowCount;
        WiCommonFunction.LoadCommonSettings();
        ShowInformation show = new ShowInformation();
        //ds = show.ShowBookImage();
        ds1 = show.ShowBookCategory();
        DataTable dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

            for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    //defining the size of cell
                    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
                }
                PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
                picture.Size = new Size(220, 180);
                picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                Byte[] byteImage = (Byte[])(dt1.Rows[j]["BookImage"]);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteImage);
                picture.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

                Label lblCategory = new Label();
                lblCategory.Text = dt1.Rows[j]["CategoryName"].ToString();

                Label lblSubCategory = new Label();
                lblCategory.Text = dt1.Rows[j]["SubCategoryName"].ToString();

                Label lblBook = new Label();
                lblBook.Text = dt1.Rows[j]["BookName"].ToString();
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picture,i,j);
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblCategory, i, j);
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblSubCategory, i, j);
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblBook, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me any solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding all four controls to each of your cells, because you execute

```
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picture,i,j);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblCategory, i, j);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblSubCategory, i, j);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblBook, i, j);
```

for every combination of (i,j). You need some kind of switch statement to add only the control you want to add into that cell, something like

```
        switch(i) {
          case 0:
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picture,i,j);
            break;
          case 1:
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblCategory, i, j);
            break;
          case 2:
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblSubCategory, i, j);
            break;
          case 3:
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblBook, i, j);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: thanks for reply.It helps me,and I get the output which I want